# Wish to import multiple rows of data from another google sheet with query & importrange function

Tags: google-sheets

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(“1faaDUoRSVzjZTSbEowsdDCBtVF-CTVaJ1vXef-qi3xU","Trial!A:Q"),"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col11 WHERE Col1 contains 'Mumbai'")
```

**Tried the above formula but not working**

Link for the Data sheet containing the data is mentioned below:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1faaDUoRSVzjZTSbEowsdDCBtVF-CTVaJ1vXef-qi3xU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: make sure that your impoprtrange is authorized beforehand you put it in QUERY

Comment: Please share your sheet publicly